# Cannot access iPhone files using my macbook via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth

I turned on bluetooth on my Macbook Air 13" (Early 2015, 8 GB RAM) and on my iPhone SE.

I'm trying to access the files from iPhone using my macbook. When trying to connect to my iPhone, it shows an error: "There was an error connecting to the device".

> [image]

However, if I start a personal hotspot on iPhone I can successfully connect via bluetooth and get internet from my phone.

Using my macbook I can successfully connect to my old Samsung S3100 phone and browse the files via bluetooth.

Also, I can use my iPhone to connect via bluetooth to my piano and get/send midi data from/to it.

I feel like just the communication between my mac and iPhone is kinda broken—it could be the cause [why AirDrop is not working too](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243427/87092).

How to fix/debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone does not support browsing files over Bluetooth.

Edit: Apple [lists](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201820) three methods for transferring data between a Mac and an iPhone.

1. AirDrop
2. Handoff
3. iCloud Drive

On that same page, Apple lists the built-in Mac browser for Bluetooth as an option for "other Bluetooth devices" and I think it is appropriate to infer that they thereby exclude the iPhone from that capability.

Comment: Is there any reference for that? I just saw another similar and short answer (which is probably true), but I'd like to know why is that.

Comment: Edited to provide further information.